# groovy parse json and save to database

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy

I want to parse a json file into objects, and save it to database. I just create a groovy script that runs in grails console(typing grails console in cmd line). I did not create grails app or domain class. Inside this small script, When I call save, I have

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Blog.save() 
  is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), isCase(java.lang.Object), 
  sleep(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Am I missing something?
I'm also confused that if I do save, is it going to save data to a table called Blog? Should I build any database connection here? (Because I grails domain class, we don't need to. But is it different using pure groovy?)

Many Thanks!

```
import grails.converters.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.*; 

class Blog {
  String title
  String body   
 static mapping = {
   body type:"text"
   attachment type:"text"
}

  Blog(title,body,slug){
    this.title = title
    this.body=body   
  }   
}
```

here parse the json

```
// parse json
List parsedList =JSON.parse(new FileInputStream("c:/ning-blogs.json"), "UTF-8")

def blogs = parsedList.collect {JSONObject jsonObject ->
    new Blog(jsonObject.get("title"),jsonObject.get("description"),"N/A");
}
```

loop blogs and save each object

```
for (i in blogs){
    // println i.title; I'll get the information needed.
    i.save();
}
```

Comment: where did you put `Blog` class?

Comment: is `Blog` a grails domain class? "Normal" classes won't automatically have a `save` method

Comment: Thanks, I haven't specify it to be domain class, I just create a groovy script that runs in grails console. Can I specify it somewhere inside groovy script? I just want it to be something simple inside script that could be run..

Answer (score 0):

I don't have large experience with grails, but from a quick googling seems like that for a class be treated like a model class, it will need to be either on the correct convention-package/dir or a [legacy jar with hibernate mapping](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/External-domain-classes-td1385541.html)/[JPA annotation](http://markmail.org/message/ct2kwmuzqow3ym2m). Thus your example can't work. Why not define that model in your model package?